# Diagonal subsequence converges at all points under these conditions

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I do not understand why the diagonal subsequence $g_n = f_{n,n}$ converges at any point $w_j$. for example, because $g_{n} (w_{20})$ it converges? From what I understand we would have $\{ f_{1,1} (w_{20}), f_{2,2} (w_{20}) , f_{3,3} (w_{20}), ... \}$. Why does it converge? If I'm wrong, someone can explain?

Answer (score 1):

Except for the first 19 terms, the sequence $(g_n)$ is a subsequence of $(f_{n,20})$, which converges at $w_{20}$.

Comment: More suppose the case $g_3(w_5)$, we have by the construction that $ g_5(w_5) $ is convergent, and $ g_5 (w_5) $ is only a subsequence of $ g_3 (w_5)$. How to guarantee the convergence of $ g_3 (w_5)$ entire?

Comment: @RicardoFreire I don't understand your comment, since $g_3(w_5)$ isn't a sequence.